# CSS page-break in asp.net listview

Tags: css, listview

I'm printing a listview page off the browser as a report.
When I'm using the page-break within the listview it breaks each item into separate page, while I want to break only before splitting the item.

Any idea how to achieve that?

---

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_allRunways" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="ListView_allRunways_ItemDataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                  <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></div>

            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
 <div class="printChk">
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>CHECKED BY</td>
                    <td style="font-weight:normal"></td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

                <div class="footer"></div>
                     <div class="page-break"> </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

-----CSS
    @media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-after:auto}
}

Comment: already tried: always, auto, avoid etc.

Comment: please show your code effort.